# Get all dates between 2 dates in vba

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am a newbie in vba and I am trying to get in vba all dates between 2 dates, for example I will call the function with the parameters 01-01-2015 and 15-01-2015, and I will get in return an array with all the dates possibles, i.e :

This is the Data that I have;

```
ID      Start Date  End Date    Code
1234567 03-10-2016  15-10-2016  ABC_987654321
3456789 10-09-2016  20-09-2016  ABC_123456789
```

The Result should be as below, and should stop when finds blanks in start date

Array

```
ID      Date        Code
1234567 03-10-2016  ABC_987654321
1234567 04-10-2016  ABC_987654321
1234567 05-10-2016  ABC_987654321
3456789 10-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 11-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 12-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 13-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 14-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 15-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 16-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 17-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 18-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 19-09-2016  ABC_123456789
3456789 20-09-2016  ABC_123456789
```

Comment: In your output, where's 6/10, 7/10, 8/10, ... 15/10/2016? You are able to drag dates down, and have the date increase by one day at a time. Does that not work?  What have you tried so far?  This is a pretty simple thing, you should find plenty of tips online. Please show what you've attempted, what has/hasn't worked.

Comment: Dates are numbers, a for next loop will help.  A bit of research would of found it for you.  Googled it About 422,000 results (0.80 seconds)

Comment: @brucewayne think o/p means up to current date (or something) :)  or end date which evers sooner.

Comment: Please [read this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) about adding demands for urgency to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing you the VBA code for this problem, with comments to help you understand the process.

Please take time to read through and understand what is happening, so next time you run into a problem like this you have an understanding of where to start. If you have a go and get stuck, then feel free to ask for help but provide information on what you have tried along with code/formulas you have used.

```
Sub ExampleMacro()

' Define the variables
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim addrows
Dim FindDates
Dim CountDays
Dim adddays
Dim i As Long
Dim ir As Long

' Workout number of rows containing data to process
With Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
End With

' This is the row number we want to start processing, every time the For runs, it will add another 1 to this number so the next row is processed
addrows = 2

' Loop through until, LastRow has been reached
For ir = 1 To LastRow

' Define the number of days between the two dates
FindDates = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & addrows).Value

' Define the number of days between the two dates
CountDays = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & addrows).Value - Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & addrows).Value + 1

' Define the date to enter into Data column on Sheet 2, every time it loops through the date will be increased by 1
adddays = 0

' Loop through until, the last date has been reached
For i = 1 To CountDays

' Insert a new blank row on Sheet2 - Row2, for the data to be entered
Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
' Put ID value of the row into Sheet2
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & addrows).Value
' Put the date into Sheet2
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = FindDates + adddays
' Put the Code into Sheet2
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & addrows).Value

' Increase the date by 1 day, ready for the re run of this loop
adddays = adddays + 1

' Go back to i and carry on until the number of CountDays has been matached.
Next I

' Now that all the dates for the first row of data has been processed, increase the row number by 1
addrows = addrows + 1

' Go back to ir and carry on until the number of rows with data has been completed
Next ir

End Sub
```